# How to map two structures with nested for loops?

Tags: scala, for-loop

I have two structures; 'pointsArray' of type (Double,Double) and 'listOfBBs' of type class List[BoundingBox]. I want to map each point to one BoundingBox. This is the code I am trying, it runs but gives an empty list '()'.

```
var PointsMappedtoGrids1 = Map[(Double,Double),BoundingBox] ()
for (point <- pointsArray)
{for{eachBB <-listOfBBs
  if point._1 >= eachBB.lowerleft._1 &&
    point._1 <= eachBB.upperright._1 &&
    point._2 >= eachBB.lowerleft._2 &&
    point._2 <= eachBB.upperright._2}
  PointsMappedtoGrids1 + (point->eachBB)}
```

Please guide or hint what should I do to obtain a mpping of all points with their corresponding boxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more functional version of the logic:

```
val PointsMappedtoGrids1: Map[(Double,Double),BoundingBox] =
  (for {
    point <- pointsArray
    bb <- listOfBBs
    if point._1 >= bb.lowerleft._1 &&
       point._1 <= bb.upperright._1 &&
       point._2 >= bb.lowerleft._2 &&
       point._2 <= bb.upperright._2
  } yield point -> bb
  )(collection.breakOut)
```

This builds the `Map` in a single pass and avoids using `var` or mutable data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want make big changes then you can try `PointsMappedtoGrids1 = PointsMappedtoGrids1 + (point-> eachBB)` rather than using `PointsMappedtoGrids1 + (point-> eachBB)`, but much better if you just use `map` because `nested for loops` will return `Unit` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for:

Assumed BoundingBox is a case class and following is the structure:

```
case class BoundingBox(lowerLeft: (Double, Double), lowerRight: (Double, Double), upperLeft: (Double, Double),
                         upperRight: (Double, Double))

  val pointArray: Array[(Double, Double)] = Array((1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 8), (5, 6))

val listOfBBs = List(BoundingBox((1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)))

  val x: Array[Map[(Double, Double), BoundingBox]] =for {
    point <- pointArray
    eachBB <- listOfBBs

    if point._1 >= eachBB.lowerLeft._1 &&
      point._1 <= eachBB.upperRight._1 &&
      point._2 >= eachBB.lowerLeft._2 &&
      point._2 <= eachBB.upperRight._2
  } yield PointsMappedtoGrids1 + (point -> eachBB)
```